# Why can't I use my TV as a dual monitor setup?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Im new to Ubuntu, and can't get it to recognise my Sony Bravia TV as a monitor. In the Displays Settings menu, it shows my regular monitor (23" BENQ) as a Laptop which concerns me a little, not sure if this is part of the problem.

I have a GeForce GTX 275 Graphics Card, with my TV plugged in through the HDMI output. It runs fine in my windows environment

Thanks

Comment: Do you have three output devices connected or two? Mine ran into problems when I had three, so I disconnected one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so then install the NVidia graphics driver.  Go to System Settings > Additional Drivers to see what is available.

Comment: I have 2 options in there and tried both - NVIDEA Accelerated Graphics Drivers (version current) [Recommended] and NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver (post-release updates) (version current-updates). Neither of them displayed anything

Comment: install the ` NVIDEA Accelerated Graphics Drivers (version current)` or via command line `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` be sure to do a reboot afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile CUDA once and the Ubuntu drivers couldn't get it off the water (it can't recognize my DVI output as a separate screen, two screens with different aspect ratio are always tied together)

Not everyone would recommend this, **but I found [NVidia's proprietary drivers](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/56283) work best for Ubuntu**. It can recognize my monitors properly, but you have to install it manually and not via Ubuntu's Additional drivers interface. Follow the instructions [here](http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/installing-cuda-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/) to install this driver (you have to blacklist Ubuntu's open source drivers first), you can skip the CUDA part.

And to be clear, [NVidia is to blame for this mess](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MShbP3OpASA#t=2951s), they hold up a lot of information to open source developers.